# Some anomalies in Julia‘s range object?

Tags: julia

### Problem description

Let's consider the following function

```
function simpson(f, a,b, n)
  h = (b-a)/n
  h2 = 2*h
  s = f(a) + 4*sum(f.((a+h):h2:(b-h))) + 2*sum(f.((a+h2):h2:(b-h2))) + f(b)
  return h*s/3
end
```

where f is a real-valued function on the interval [a,b] which is subdivided into n (an even integer ≥ 4) subintervals of equal length.

The expression `sf(n) = simpson(x->1/x, 0.01,1, n)` calculates an approximation to the integral of f(x)=1/x (-ln(0.01)) as a function of n; the error being sf(n)+log(0.01).

#### Graphic

A loglog plot on the range 10:10:1000 shows some interesting spikes:

[Spikes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLgm0.png)

(In fact, the graph shows `abs(sf(n) + log(0.01))` because at the positions n=320, etc: sf(n) ≤ -log(0.01) !)

The spikes disappear if the line defining s is replaced by

```
s = f(a) + 4*sum([fa+k*h) for k in 1:2:(n-1)]) + 2*sum([f(a+k*h) for k in 2:2:(n-1)]) +f(b)
```

(The corresponding curve has been superimposed on the main one in the preceding graph.)

### Question

Why do the spikes appear at those precise values 30, 60, 320, 490, 640, 870, 980?

(In `R`, the corresponding range function `seq` does not produce any spikes.)

### Summary of the responses

Thank you all for your contributions.
All the answers to my question try to explain the appearance of spikes by the accumulation of floating point errors during repeated addition & suggest some methods to avoid such problems.
All this is correct & useful, but there remain some problems:

- the general cause (floating point errors) does not explain the precise values at which the `range` function gives a wrong result & that they are after all relatively rare
- one may suppose, that this general cause is made worse within a `while` loop; this seems to be true for a `Julia` loop, from which observation I deduce that `range` makes a real effort to compensate for those errors
- but I transposed the `while` loop I had written in `Julia` to the ”arbitrary precision calculator” `Calc`where the results are flawless, i.e. the  graphic does not have spikes
- is broadcasting over a suitably defined `range`or `LinRange`really better (in what sense?) than using a list comprehension as I did (`[f(a+k*h) for k …]`)?

I have used [Mikaels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370594/mikael-%C3%96hman) proposition & wrote some code which shows which of the two ranges is off (by 1); alas, I do not see any pattern emerging from those statistics:

| n | n1 | n2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 1 | 1 |
| 60 | 0 | 1 |
| 320 | 1 | 0 |
| 490 | 1 | 0 |
| 640 | 0 | 1 |
| 870 | 0 | 1 |
| 980 | 0 | 1 |
| 1060 | 1 | 0 |
| 1320 | 1 | 0 |
| 1330 | 0 | 1 |

But trying to articulate & represent precisely what one does not understand remains a worthwhile exercise, even if the initial problem remains unsolved. Thanks for participating.

Comment: Is it possible you have a typo in `4*sum(f.((a+h):h2:(b-h)))`, and it is supposed to be `4*sum(f.((a+h):h:(b-h)))`? Otherwise, it does not correspond to `4*sum([fa+k*h) for k in 1:2:(n-1)])` part of the code  producing the curve without spikes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I don't think this is the reason: the step is `h2` (i.e. `2*h`), not `h`.

Answer (score 6):

The `a:b:c` construct means to increment by `b` until it exceeds `c`.
Rounding errors when the increment, start, or end are floating point numbers runs the risk of ever so slightly rounding off higher or lower than expected.

We can detect this by adding a bit of instrumentation:

```
function simpson(f, a,b, n)
  h = (b-a)/n
  h2 = 2*h
  first_range = (a+h):h2:(b-h)
  second_range = (a+h2):h2:(b-h2)
  n1 = length(first_range)
  n2 = length(second_range)
  println(n, ' ', n1, ' ', n2)
  @assert n == n1 + n2
  s = f(a) + 4*sum(f.(first_range)) + 2*sum(f.(second_range)) + f(b)
  return h*s/3
end
```

This is not a bug with ranges, they work exactly as described, the issue is trying to rely on exact floating point math, which isn't a thing.
For these particular numbers, you happen to hit the first such rounding error at `n=30`.

The right tool for these ranges is `LinRange(a, b, n)`.

```
function simpson(f, a,b, n)
  h = (b-a)/n
  h2 = 2*h
  first_range = LinRange(a+h, b-h, n÷2)
  second_range = LinRange(a+h2, b-h2, n÷2)
  n1 = length(first_range)
  n2 = length(second_range)
  #println(n, ' ', n1, ' ', n2)
  @assert n == n1 + n2  # this can't fail now
  s = f(a) + 4*sum(f.(first_range)) + 2*sum(f.(second_range)) + f(b)
  return h*s/3
end
```

Even in `R`, it looks like `seq` has a `length.out` parameter, which I would suggest is the only correct third argument to use here (which would be the equivalent of `LinRange` in Julia).

Edit: Based on @DNF comment i had a closer look, I hadn't realized that `range` actually has an optional `length` argument (much like `seq`), i.e:

```
first_range = range(a+h, b-h, length=n÷2)
```

which has a bit more overhead but does some additional corrections compared to `LinRange` (see help) where is improves accuracy of increments. To be clear, this is not what has caused the errors you have seen; it is caused by using the increment for a floating point range. I think you are unlikely to see any difference for this function.

### Follow up answers:

Edit 2: Since additional questions appeared:

> the general cause (floating point errors) does not explain the precise values at which the range function gives a wrong result & that they are after all relatively rare

No this is the explanation. You are relying on floating point math of small increments adding up to exactly a specific value. Sometimes it happens to work out, sometimes not. Pick more "evil" numbers (how about n=17), and you will see more. You can go through the IEEE 754 arithmetic bit for bit if you want to confirm. I wouldn't expect to find any patterns, as it depends on your choice of a, b, and n.

You are also not seeing the the cases where the end value is ever slightly smaller. Feel free to add it this as well

```
@assert last(first_range) == b-h
@assert last(second_range) == b-h2
```

and you will see the a lot more errors.

> one may suppose, that this general cause is made worse within a while loop; this seems to be true for a Julia loop, from which observation I deduce that range makes a real effort to compensate for those errors

You have no while loop, so I assume you are referring to when you do `[fa+k*h) for k in 1:2:(n-1)]`.

No, this is basically constructing a poor mans `LinRange` with fixed length. It does not rely on any floats to determine the exact end condition; it is based on `1:2:(n-1)` which are all integers and of course won't have these issue.

> is broadcasting over a suitably defined `range`or `LinRange` really better (in what sense?) than using a list comprehension as I did ([f(a+k*h) for k …])?

Very slightly better yes. `LinRange` will use `lerpi`, linearly interpolate the value based on the index (i.e. `t = i/n` and `a*(1-t) + t*b`. `range` would do ever more corrections to the floats.

Would you notice this difference in these plots? No.

> (In R, the corresponding range function seq does not produce any spikes.)

It seems `seq` in R  has a nudge factor in it's `seq` implementation.

```
> seq(0,0.6, 0.3)
[1] 0.0000000000000000000 0.2999999999999999889 0.5999999999999999778
> seq(0,0.59999999999, 0.3)
[1] 0.00000000000000000000 0.29999999999999998890 0.59999999998999997697
```

basically it ignores your requested increment in order to squeeze in the last value. Yikes! But even then only up to a point;

```
> seq(0,0.5999999999, 0.3)
[1] 0.00000000000000000000 0.29999999999999998890
```

so if you had some computation here which had worse than 1e-10 precision, you'd see the same thing in `R`. Again solved by replacing the end condition with the length instead of relying on the increment.

Comment: For accuracy you may be better off using the  `range` function rather than `LinRange`.

Comment: Indeed, you can even write `range(a+h, b-h, n÷2)` without the keyword.

Comment: Thank you.
I supposed (& verified) the `f.LinRange` solution would be equivalent to my `[f(a+k*h) for k … ]`solution (which, by the way, was somewhat simpler from a type point of view).
The `R`function `seq` method I mentioned was the `seq(from,to,by)` variant, i.e. exactly the equivalent of my `Julia range` constructor, as I was interested in working with *increments*, having read in the `Julia 1.9.2` manual (p 695) : 

«Compared to using `range`, directly constructing a `LinRange`  should have less overhead but won't try to correct for floating point errors»

Comment: **Addendum** | The assertion error is triggered only for n=30,320, 490.

Comment: Working with increments is bad for floats when you rely on them adding up exactly to the end value. Floating point math isn't exact, and what you truly need is a linear space. 
For example. `seq(0, 0.99999999999, 1/3)` vs `seq(0, 1, 1/3)`, we see that `seq` nudges the increment based on the end value (up to a point). I don't know how big nudge-factor they added into `seq`.

Comment: I fixed a typo in my code, i had wrongly set `n2 = length(first_range)` so it didn't detect the case when only the second range fell short.

Comment: Thank you. I had overlooked the typo myself … If we now test for the condition n-1 == n1+n2, then we can reproduce the whole sequence of strange numbers.

Comment: @MarcJCharpentier I hope my edited follow up answers all your remaining questions. I really only comes down to not using the inexact floating point increment for the end condition.

Comment: Thank you, Mikael, for your patience & precise answers.
Concerning the `while` loop: I did not refer to list comprehensions, I wrote a real incremental `while` loop, which I could transfer as such to `Calc`.; as `Calc` works with rational approximations, it is often rather slow: speed & precision remain contradictory goals.
But, of course, you are right: the *main* force behind all those spikes & deviations is the very nature of floating point numbers.

Comment: Out of pure wantonness, I had a look at the values, `Haskell` produces with its native range function. The additive, incremental version produces a perfect error curve; no spikes at all.
A `Scheme` implementation of the Simpson algorithm however is an excellent illustration of your main point, far better than the `Julia` version.

Comment: Well i don't know what more you want from an answer here. Looking up what haskells range does with floats; it's actually defined to increment until it become greater than `b + h/2`. It's not the same function. R and Haskell both different from each other, and different from Julia. Julia does the same as Matlab or `np.arange`, where you get exactly what you asked for, no special rules. All methods involving the increment will be numerically less accurate than the `lerpi` based one.

Answer (score 1):

While Mikael made a very clear answer, another thing worth noting is that in Julia you can create ranges with rational numbers and than avoid the rounding problem altogether (might make sense or not depending on scenario).

For an example (7 element range from 2 to 5):

```
julia> 2:(5-2)//7:5
2//1:3//7:5//1

julia> collect(2:(5-2)//7:5)
8-element Vector{Rational{Int64}}:
  2//1
 17//7
 20//7
 23//7
 26//7
 29//7
 32//7
  5//1
```

This works with `range` too:

```
julia> range(2//1,5//1, 8)
8-element LinRange{Rational{Int64}, Int64}:
 2//1, 17//7, 20//7, 23//7, 26//7, 29//7, 32//7, 5//1
```

Comment: Thank you. I have alluded to your suggestions in my Summary of the Responses (see above).